# Why doesn't ConfigureAwait(false) work with Task.Run/Task.Yield?

Tags: .net, executioncontext

Here is a little test I wrote.

```
        Assert.False(ExecutionContext.IsFlowSuppressed()); // Precondition

        await Task.Run(() => Task.Yield()).ConfigureAwait(false);

        var isSuppressed = Utility.WasExecutionContextActuallySuppressed();
        Assert.True(isSuppressed);
```

However, the code 'WasExecutionContextActuallySuppressed that walks the stack, returns false - indicating the context was not suppressed - since the stack shows ExecutionContext.Run is the caller:

Stack:

1. <b__6_0>d.MoveNext
2. MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext
3. ExecutionContext.RunInternal
4. ExecutionContext.Run

Why doesn't this work?

(Note: on the other hand if I actually do `ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow();` instead of using `ConfigureAwait(false)`, it seems to work!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ConfigureAwait(false)` has nothing to do with suppressing the execution context. It only controls one thing: whether the captured `SynchronizationContext` or `TaskScheduler` is used to resume execution after the `await` completes.